# Trigger a js animation when opening the page

Tags: javascript

I want to launch an animation as soon as my home page opens, but it takes time to display (the body remains displayed for a while).
My script :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.logo').hide();
});

$(window).load(function(){
    $('.logo').fadeIn('fast');
    $(".logo").animate({
        marginTop:'0px',
        opacity:1
    },200,'swing');
});
```

I tried to manipulate this code but I'm new to javascript :(

Answer (score 0):

Great thanks a lot. I just forgot to say that the logo goes up. I forgot to script. I'm giving you all of it, but of course just the fact that the logo goes up is enough for me. Thanks again, you're GREAT :)

```
<!-- /logo descend -->
    $(window).on('load', function() {
  $('.logo').hide().fadeIn('fast').animate({marginTop:'0px', opacity:1}, 500, 'swing');
});


<!-- /Slider goes up a bit -->

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#slider').hide();
});
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#slider').fadeIn('slow');
    $("#slider").delay(400).animate({
        marginTop:'-1200px',
        opacity:1
    },800,'swing');
});
<!-- /logo and Slider rise (2 scripts) -->

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.logo').hide();
});
$(window).load(function(){
    $('.logo').fadeIn('slow');
    $(".logo").delay(200).animate({
        marginTop:'-2400px',
        opacity:1
    },800,'swing');
});


$(document).ready(function(){
    $('sl.slider').hide();
});
$(window).load(function(){
    $('.sl-slider').fadeIn('slow');
    $(".sl-slider").delay(800).animate({
        marginTop:'0px',
        opacity:1
    },800,'swing');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the keyword `defer` to your `<script>` call on your HTML head element. This will make sure your script executes right after the contents of your HTML file have been parsed.

Here is a snippet of some boilerplate code generated with VSCode.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="index.js" defer></script>
    <title>Your Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Your code goes here -->
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, I have included the `defer` keyword inside the opening script tag declaration.

Comment: Thank you for wanting to help me, it's very kind. But I suck at javascript :(
Can you give me an example code?
Thank you so much ;)

Comment: @Hans, I have updated my answer as per your concern. If it does not help, please do not hesitate to ask.

Comment: Good morning Jonathan,
My code does not work after Daredev's (which fixed a lot of bugs). That of the logo going down. :( Thank you for your precious help. ;)

Comment: Hi Jonathan,
How are you ?
What do I put in the .js (head / defer), only the logo script that descends or the entire animation? (logo that goes up with a slider).
THANKS

Answer (score 0):

Yes!! I have a code that works :) Is it correct? Is there a way to make the animation (logo) arrive earlier? As soon as the page is opened? Thank you so much :)

```
<script>
    $(window).on('load', function() {
      $('.logo').hide().fadeIn('fast').animate({marginTop:'0px', opacity:1}, 200, 'swing');
    });
    </script>
    
    
    <!-- /slider monte en parti -->
    
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#slider').hide();
    });
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('#slider').fadeIn('slow');
        $("#slider").delay(400).animate({
            marginTop:'-1200px',
            opacity:1
        },800,'swing');
    });
    </script>
    
    
    <!-- /barre de nav -->
    
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.nav').hide();
    });
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('.nav').fadeIn('slow');
        $(".nav").delay(700).animate({
            left:'0px',
            opacity:1
        },1200,'swing');
    });
    </script>
    
    
    
    <!-- /logo et sl-slider montent (2 scripts) -->
    
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.logo').hide();
    });
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('.logo').fadeIn('slow');
        $(".logo").delay(800).animate({
            marginTop:'-2400px',
            opacity:1
        },800,'swing');
    });
    </script>
    
    
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('sl.slider').hide();
    });
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('.sl-slider').fadeIn('slow');
        $(".sl-slider").delay(800).animate({
            marginTop:'0px',
            opacity:1
        },800,'swing');
    });
    </script>
```